# Is it possible for an experienced developer to get a shot for entry level job at Google?

Tags: interviewing, career-development, job-change, careers

I am working as a Software Engineer in a Product development firm with 7 years of experience and limited skills.

I would like to start fresh improve my skills in competitive programming and go for big companies like Google, Microsoft etc.

1. Is it possible for experienced engineers to get a call for entry level Jobs in Big companies?
2. Is it a good idea overall? What can be my plan B if I fail in this plan?

Comment: Are you talking about applying for positions where a company has specifically advertised for a recent graduate?

Comment: Yes. In other words is it possible for me to apply and get a call for Software Engineer role rather than Lead Engineer or Senior development engineer role.

Comment: Why negatively paint yourself with "limited skills?"

Comment: I some how have idea on whats required by Google and Microsoft. When I compare my skills with what is expected, "limited skills" is the natural word that comes out.

Comment: they hire junior devs directly from the top schools and companies

Answer (score 12):

It's doubtful.  Companies like this would rather foster young talent for entry level jobs rather than experienced developers simply wanting an easy route into the company by picking a lower grade job.  Regardless of how you justify this attempt, this is how it will be viewed by the hiring managers.

Take the hard way in - go for the jobs that demand the experience you actually have.

Comment: Agree with this. It's probably worth mentioning that most big companies will just put your application straight into the big pile of general applications if you apply for a specific role you are not qualified for.